# Extracting text from docx as key value pair giving attribute error

Tags: python, regex, docx

I have a Docx files which looks like this

```
Requisition No: VOI9053459-
 
Job location: Melbourn
 
Exp : 2 – 4 Years
 
Notice period :-15day or less
```

with other details in it. I wanted to extract certain key-value pair from the document and save it as a dictionary. the document has been extracted and assigned to

```py
for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
    if isinstance(child, CT_P):
        yield Paragraph(child, parent)
text = block.text
```

My progress so far is

```py
job_location = re.compile(r'(^Job?.*\S+?)')
notice_period = re.compile(r'(^Notice?.*\d\w*.+\S+?)')
experience = re.compile(r'(^Exp.*\S+?)')

job_location = job_location.search(text)
key_value1 = job_location.group()
split1 = re.split(': |-', key_value1)
keys.append(split1[0])
data.append(split1[1])

notice_period = notice_period.search(text)
key_value2 = notice_period.group()
split2 = re.split(': |-', key_value2)
keys.append(split2[0])
data.append(split2[1])

experience = experience.search(text)
key_value3 = experience.group()
split3 = re.split(': |-', key_value3)
keys.append(split3[0])
data.append(split3[1])

for key in keys:
    col.append((key, []))
i = 0
for j in range(len(data)):
    T = data[j]

    col[i][1].append(T)
    i += 1
Dict = {keys: data for (keys, data) in col}

print(Dict)
```

I am getting the attribute error

```
> AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-261-84c60112ddb2> in <module>
>      82 
>      83 
> ---> 84 convert_docx_to_text(file_path=(r'data_extraction.docx'))
> 
> <ipython-input-261-84c60112ddb2> in convert_docx_to_text(file_path)
>      51 
>      52             job_location=job_location.search(text)
> ---> 53             key_value1=job_location.group()
>      54             split1=re.split(': |-',key_value1)
>      55             keys.append(split1[0])
> 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why is it not working? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The error indicates that `job_location=job_location.search(text)` did not return a match.

Comment: But I used regex stimulator to create that regex and it worked back then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your regular expressions. Let's take the regex for searching for the job location. You have:

```
r'(^Job?.*\S+?)'
```

1. First, without using `flags=re.MULTILINE`, the `^` character will only match the start of string rather than the start of a line.
2. `Job?` matches `Jo` *optionally* followed by a `b`.
3. In the absence of `flags=re.DOTALL`, `.*` will *greedily* match *any* non-newline character 0 or more times.
4. `\S+?` will optionally match 1 or more non-white space characters.

For example, your regex would match the line: `Joabcdefg` with `.*` matching `abcdef` and `\S+?` matching `g`.

You also make a call on the `group` method of a `match` object. But you must pass an integer to this method specifying which group number you are interested in.

The regex you need to search for a job location is given in the following example:

```
import re

text = """=Requisition No: VOI9053459-

Job location: Melbourn

Exp : 2 – 4 Years

Notice period :-15day or less"""

job_location_re = re.compile(r'(?:^Job\s+location:\s+)(.*)$', re.MULTILINE)
m = job_location_re.search(text)
if m: # there is a match
    job_location = m.group(1)
    print(job_location)
```

Prints:

```
Melbourn
```

Notice that I have called the compiled regex `job_location_re` rather than using the name `job_location` for both the regex and the name of the location.

1. `(?^Job\s+location:\s+)` matches `Job location:` at the start of a line allowing one or more spaces between `Job` and `location:` and after `location:`. This is done in a *non-capturing* group.
2. `(.*)` matches *greedily* any non-newline character up to the end of line. This will be group 1.
3. `$` matches the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this code, this should work

Edit 1 to improve code, split only first coincidence

```
split3=re.split(': |-',key_value3, 1)
#keys.append(split3[0])
#data.append(split3[1])
k,v = split3
your_dict[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to this line `job_location = job_location.search(text)`, the search was unsuccessful, because `job_location = None`, and therefore an error occurs that you won’t get anything from `None`, you either need to change the `text` or work with `job_location`

Comment: I worked on it seperately and it was working fine. Dont know what went wrong when I joined it

Comment: try using debug mode or change the code like this:

job_location = job_location.findall (text)
print (job_location)

if the array is empty, you need to work with compile and / or text extraction

Comment: It returned some empyt arrays and the job location. Is it because of the empty arrays it is throwing error? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: yes, the error is that when searching, the code does not find anything (a bit of theory): findall returns all the entries in the string, search is only the first, it is recommended to use findall, because it is more universal, and replaces search. just refer to the first element of the array: job_location = job_location.findall (text) [0] <=> job_location = job_location.search (text)
and notice_period.group () tries to work with this first entry (which is not - None) and gets an error, because can't work with empty space

Comment: you should pay attention to job_location=re.compile and text, some of this works incorrectly

Comment: 1 - check the correctness of the text. (print (text))
How do you extract text from a document?

Comment: print(text) returns the same result, which I had posted in the question. Actually it is a part of data extraction Im working on.

Comment: ok, the problem is re.compile (r '(^ Job?. * \ S +?)'), it is not compiled correctly, since we are not getting anything, what do you need to get?

Comment: It is actually giving the output 'Job location: Melbourn' when I print it. but I cant make these codes work. key_value1=job_location.group().text
            split1=re.split(': |-',key_value1)
            keys.append(split1[0])
            data.append(split1[1])

Comment: firstly, my findall and search return only empty arrays
secondly, if your re.compile returns, then what you need, I don’t see any obstacles for the code to work

Comment: one more thing you don't need .group (), just use split

Comment: *either .group () or split